# FastAPI with uvicorn doesn't update

Tags: python, fastapi

I am using FastAPI with Uvicorn. Everything was working perfectly, but now it seems that nothing is updating. I have changed a method and it does not recognize the change, I have created a new method and it does not recognize it either. Execution: uvicorn `API:app --reload`.

For example, this is a simple code that does not recognize:

```
@app.get("/clientes/cumple", response_model=List[Cliente])
async def get_cliente_cumple(dia: int, mes: int):
    clientes = db.obtener_clientes_por_fecha_nacimiento(dia, mes)
    if not clientes:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Cliente no encontrado")
    return [Cliente(codigoclientes=c["codigoclientes"],titular=c["titular"],fnacim=c["fnacim"],dni_cif=c["dni_cif"], telf=c["telf"]) for c in clientes]
```

I finish it and restart, but nothing changes.

In the terminal where I execute the API, it looks like it recognize the changes, but usually when I do a request, the terminal also shows the HTTP Code result and right now only shows the alleged changes.

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: Check that you have only one instance of your app running

Comment: Check if your path does not conflict with other paths

Comment: You didn't include the log that show the reload issue, but uvicorn + pycharm on Windows has an outstanding issue: https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/2000 about reloads. If you're stopping uvicorn completely and starting it again and it doesn't reflect any changes, make sure that there isn't an issue with the created pyc files (remove them manully and test again), and verify that, as Motov says, you're not running another server somewhere that is answering (try making a request after stopping the server)

Comment: In addition to @MatsLindh: check how you instantiate your app, does it contain an URL? 
```app = FastAPI(servers="<url>")```

Comment: `servers` is [only relevant for the generated OpenAPI specification](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/#additional-servers) (and what gets shown in the swagger/redoc UIs), so hopefully it shouldn't affect antyhing in this case.

Comment: Its solved. When I finished the run, it didn't actually finish, so it didn't update. Thank you guys. @CharlieV, I instantiate of this form: `app = FastAPI()`, it doesn`t contain any URL. Should I write the URL there? Explain me if you can please.